# My css messes up the text

Tags: html, css

i'm currently trying to make my CV stand out, make it be special however when trying to  add text the text falls in with the logo. My aim is to have white boxes going over the logo, not sure if that's possible but anyhow. Any help? Much appreciated.

```css
.container {
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
}

.centered {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.boxed {
 margin: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: black 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<div class="codepad-logo">
    <div class="logo"></div>
 
<div class="centered">
  test
</div>
</html>
```

Edit #1:

[enter link description here](http://dev.dlgames.co.uk) The text in the middle (test)i want to be in a white box above the logo, another box where the logo is. So, the text should be above the logo and straight, not slanted.

Comment: Can you add the CSS of the classes logo and code-pad logo impossible to solve your question now.

Comment: I agree with @WillemvanderVeen, it sounds like you need to do a background image or something along those lines but it would be good to have an example image at least

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you want a centered title text, and a centered logo underneath it. Given that, you can use `flexbox` for centering and simply order your html in the order you want your elements to appear.

```css
.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
  // border: thin solid black; --> uncomment this to see the border
}

.logo {
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 100px;
  // border: thin solid black; --> uncomment this to see the border
}
```

```html
<html>

<div class="codepad-logo ">
  <div class="centered title">test</div>
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="https://i0.wp.com/royalepremierleague.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/css-logo.png" class="logo" />
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```